# Java Servlet getInputStream error

Tags: java, servlets

I'm learning Java Servlets and the book I'm using has an example on file upload , when I do it I get the following error

> The method getInputStream() is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse

When I try to use

```
ServletInputStream sis =  response.getInputStream();
```

One of the solution eclipse offered was

```
ServletInputStream sis =  ((ServletRequest) response).getInputStream();
```

And using that resulted in the following

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade cannot be cast
>
> > to javax.servlet.ServletRequest     ShowForm.doPost(ShowForm.java:37)
> >         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
> >         javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

**Here is my full code:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ShowForm
 */
@WebServlet("/ShowForm")
public class ShowForm extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ShowForm() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            doPost(request,response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        ServletInputStream sis =  response.getInputStream();
        for (int i = sis.read();i != -1; i = sis.read())
            {

                out.print((char)i);

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Comment: Try to understand the concept of request and response. From the server point of view, a request is what is coming "in" and therefore you have an INputstream. A response is the answer to the request and is therefore what is going "out" and it has an OUTputstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `ServletResponse`/`HttpServletResponse` doesn't have the `getInputStream()`. 
You might actually want to use `getInputStream` from `HttpServletRequest`.

```
request.getInputStream()
```

Comment: Thanks :) that fixed it , there was a typo in the book >.<

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the original error:

> the method getInputStream() is undefined for the type HttpServletResponse

This is telling you the problem.  `HttpServletResponse` has no `getInputStream()` method - it doesn't make sense for it to have one.

`getInputStream()` is on `HttpServletRequest`.

Eclipse can be a bit of an idiot when it comes to auto-fix suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an InputStream from HttpServletRequest.
Instead from an HttpServletOutputStream you can get the OutputStream.
It make sense, because usually you'd like to read the incoming request, and write a reply accordingly.